# Выпадающее по клику меню на css

Tags: меню, css

Приветствую!

Скажите, как сделать выпадающее по клику меню, желательно на css, с такой особенностью: меню убирается не только по нажатию на ссылку, но и на любое место пространства вне этого меню. Пример: такие меню часто встречаются на Яндексе и Гугле.

Comment: Если не морочить себе голову то можно обойтись исключительно css. Но учитывая показатель данных GA(гугль аналитикс) 12-15% посетителей сайта все еще юзают злостный IE6. Если у сайта нет коммерческого интереса то ответ ниже. Если же сайт занимается привлечением клиентов, да еще и вкладываются финансы на рекламу и раскрутку то о ишаке забывать нельзя. Обработчик js должен присутствовать однозначно.

Comment: Все верно насчет IE6, сайт коммерческий, да еще к тому же провинциальный, где по всей видимости и живут эти самые 12-15% (хотя не обязательно). Поэтому буду рад узнать решение для IE6 даже с использованием скриптов.

Comment: Посоветую Jquery, реализация будет в ответе.

Answer (score 7):

Выпадающее меню по клику

```
HTML код
<a class="main-item" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1" >Открыть подменю</a> 
<ul class="sub-menu"> 
   <li><a href="#1">подпункт 1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#2">подпункт 2</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#3">подпункт 3</a></li> 
</ul> 

CSS код
.sub-menu 
{ 
   display: none; 
} 
.main-item:focus ~ .sub-menu, 
.main-item:active ~ .sub-menu, 
.sub-menu:hover 
{ 
   display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Bomblerm спрашивает: TomasRedl, а можно к меню добавить какую-либо анимацию, например, выход, как в ВКонтакте, когда нажимаешь на своё имя и аватарку?

Comment: да можно, но это на JS лучше делать или генератором css

Answer (score 3):

я однажды реализовывал подобное меню. там смысл достаточно прост: делаем обычное навигационное меню. раз меню выпадающее - делаем первый и второй уровень (допустим). первый уровень отображается всегда, а вот второй скрываем с помощью `display: none;`. при наведении на определённый пункт меню первого уровня через псевдокласс `:hover` отображаем ссылки второго уровня.
тут правильно задать позиционирование для второго уровня. а также очень важно (это проблема заставила меня долго мучаться) задать для пункта, при наведении на который будет появляться подменю, `padding` по-больше. чтобы площадь реагирования на наведение увеличить.
Для большей наглядности мой код HTML (упрощённый):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD//XTHML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtm1" xml:lang="en" lang="ru">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="main_nav">
            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Услуги</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Все виды оценки</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Автоэкспертиза</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Автострахование</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Юридические услуги</a></li>
                </ul><!--end sub_nav-->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Тарифы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul><!--end main_nav-->
</body>
</html>
```

И код CSS (тоже упрощён):

```
#main_nav {
            position: relative;
            top: 15px;
            margin-top: 14px;
            margin-left: 280px;
            }
        #main_nav li{
            display: inline;
            padding: 0 8px;
            border-left: 1px dotted #8b6619;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            }
        #main_nav li:first-child, #main_nav ul li {
            border-left: none;
            }
        #main_nav ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 19px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 155px;
            }
        #main_nav li a, #main_nav li ul li a{
            color: #8b6619;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: none;
            padding-bottom: 17px;
            }
        #main_nav li a:hover, 
        #main_nav li ul a:hover {
            color: black;
            }
        /*--------------Подменю--------------*/
            #main_nav li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                }
```

Вот и всё. Спасибо за голоса!)

Comment: а как же ie6?

Comment: @Palmervan а как же Netscape?

Comment: @smellyshovel, IE и Netscape нужны только для того, чтобы можно было скачать нормальный браузер...

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
  { 
  $('#nav li').hover(
  function () {
    $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
  }, 
  function () {
    $('ul', this).slideUp(100);         
  }
  );    
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#nav {
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  list-style:none;
}   
#nav li {
  float:left; 
  display:block; 
  width:100px; 
  background:#ccc; 
  position:relative;
  z-index:500; 
  margin:0 1px;
}

#nav li a {
  display:block; 
  padding:8px 5px 0 5px; 
  font-weight:700;  
  height:23px; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:#fff; 
  text-align:center; 
  color:#333;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color:#fff;
}
#nav a.selected {
  color:#f00;
}
#nav ul {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  display:none; 
  margin:0 0 0 -1px; 
  padding:0; 
  list-style:none;
}
#nav ul li {
  width:100px; 
  float:left; 
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
#nav ul a {
  display:block;  
  height:15px;
  padding: 8px 5px; 
  color:#666;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;    
}
*html #nav ul {
  margin:0 0 0 -2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Parent 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Parent 02 > </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Item 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 03 > </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 04</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 07</a></li>
    </ul>           
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 04</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но хотелось бы открывать меню по клику, а не по наведению. А закрывать по клику не только на кнопку но и в любое место пространства... Пример есть тут же на этой странице, в левой верхней части есть, рядом с "править", пунктик "еще", вот он открывается и закрывается как надо.