# Всплывающее меню для ячеек таблицы

Tags: html

При наведении на ячейку таблицы должно выводиться всплывающее меню. Как сделать так, чтобы оно выводилось относительно той ячейки, на которую наводится мышка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь Вы поиском перед тем, как вопрос задавать!
Например, вот аналогичная тема: [Всплывающее меню на CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/52381/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#52444)

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто. В ячейку помещаешь **DIV** со свойством **position: relative**, а в этот DIV помещаешь другой **DIV** со свойством **position: absolute** в котором и должно лежать всплывающая менюшка. Ну детали не расписываю про видимость блоков.